# Резко возрастает iops на linux сервере с mysql и ssd

Tags: mysql, ssd

Сразу скажу, я еще нуб в базах.

Использую mysql(innodb) с минимальными правками в my.cnf.
База порядка 10гб. Все запросы очень простые(select id from table where = ... limit 1). Запись вообще на самом минимальном уровне и с ней проблем нет( iops не скачет). 
Приложение на java(обертка) многопоточно(15 потоков запускает юзер раз в 10 мин) дергает небольшие данные каждым потоком (около 150кб ). Юзеров онлайн обычно не больше 20.
Но вот именно это ничтожное количество юзеров создают такую нагрузку.

Поначитался литературы на эту тему и примерно понял, что проблема в том, что чтение с ssd пары килобайт данных умножается в несколько раз по отношению к ssd диску, тем самым поднимая iops.

Хостинг провайдер меня уже неоднократно блокирует за превышение iops(среднее значение 3000iops). Я же продолжаю ковырять свое java приложение и ничего не понимаю... как бы в java я уже не нуб.

Вопрос: как оптимизировать mysql(innodb) для простых запросов на ssd диске не превышая iops.

Comment: оперативной памяти то сколько на сервере?

Comment: 4 ядра 8 gb. памяти использется максимум 2gb. java машине выделено 4gb (по факту использует около 1)

Comment: Вы тут сами пишете, что "все запросы очень простые" и приводите пример только выбор id по условию (причем еще и условие не написали какого вида бывают). Из чего можно предположить, что Вам не настройка базы нужна, а оптимизация запросов. Объединяйте запросы в один там, где можно. Изучите запросы в приложении и составьте необходимые индексы.